# Test if an object implements an interface

Tags: vb.net

I have an object parameter and I need to check if the object implements a specified interface in vb.net. How to test this?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a great question, matches my search query in google exactly and has an answer.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Use [TypeOf...Is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ec5kw18.aspx):

```
If TypeOf objectParameter Is ISpecifiedInterface Then
    'do stuff
End If
```

Comment: Note that if "do stuff" requires invoking a member of the interface on the object, you probably want to use 'As' to cast and then ensure object 'IsNot Nothing'.  (This prevents an unnecessary second cast.)

Answer (score 8):

I also found this [article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DoesATypeImplementAnInterface.aspx) by Scott Hansleman to be particularly helpful with this.  In it, he recommends

**C#**

```
if (typeof(IWhateverable).IsAssignableFrom(myType)) { ... }
```

I ended up doing:

**VB.Net**

```
Dim _interfaceList As List(Of Type) = myInstance.GetType().GetInterfaces().ToList()
If _interfaceList.Contains(GetType(IMyInterface)) Then
   'Do the stuff
End If
```

Answer (score 4):

requiredInterface.IsAssignableFrom(representedType)

both requiredInterface and representedType are Types

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple way to determine whether a given object variable "o" implements a specific interface "ISomething":

```
If o.GetType().GetInterfaces().Contains(GetType(ISomething)) Then
    ' The interface is implemented
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a `List(Of String)` and the `TypeOf tmp Is IList` returns `False`. A List(Of T) implements multiple interfaces (IEnumerable, IList, ...) and checking just one requires the following snippet in VB:

```
If tmp.GetInterfaces().Contains(GetType(IEnumerable)) Then
  // do stuff...
End If
```